# Rails 5: @post.comments is empty, yet <% if @post.comments %> doesn't execute the else block and instead acts as if true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

**Rails 5 app**

I'm having an issue where inside a view I have a simple set of ERB tags:

```
<% if @post.comments %>
  <p>Comments here</p>
<% else %>
  <p>No comments yet</p>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, if comments don't exist within `@post`, to execute the bottom block of code. There are **no comments** in the database, either attached to this `@post` or any other `post`. However, it's executing the top block and I'm seeing `<p>Comments here</p>` rendered on the page.

If I `byebug` inside the view, `@post.commments.any?` returns `false`. and `@post.comments` returns:

```
Comment Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 4], ["commentable_type", "Post"]]
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Does this not count as false? Shouldn't `<% if @post.comments %>` go to the `else` block?

Schema:

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.integer  "commentable_id"
  t.string   "commentable_type"
end

create_table "forums", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_forums_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "forum_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["forum_id"], name: "index_posts_on_forum_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  ...
  # Devise stuff removed for brevity.
  ...
end

add_foreign_key "posts", "forums"
add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
```

My models:

```
#User model.
has_many :forums
has_many :posts

#Forum model.
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts

#Post model.
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forum

#Comment model.
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in Ruby just `false` and `nil` are falsey values. I mean, those values that are false in a boolean context. In your code probably `@post.comments` is `[]` and `[]` is `true` in Ruby.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought about that. I don't know why I didn't, it's not my first time with Rails. I blame the end of the work day.

`@post.comments.any?` is the solution.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Its because `@post.comments` has no recordas, and an empty array is a true object in ruby. Only nil and false are false.

You should change your code to ask `if @post.comments.present?`